# Efficient way to use a csv.Reader() for a "chan string"

Tags: go

I have a "chan string", where each entry is a CSV log line that I would like to convert to columns "[]string", currently I am (un-efficiently) creating a csv.NewReader(strings.NewReader(i)) for each item, which looks a lot more work than it really needs to be:

```
for i := range feederChan {
    r := csv.NewReader(strings.NewReader(i))
    a, err := r.Read()
    if err != nil {
         // log error...
         continue
    }
    // then do stuff with 'a'
    // ...
}
```

So, I'd really appreciate sharing if there's a more efficient way to do that, like creating the csv.Reader once, then feeding it the chan content somehow (stream 'chan' content to something that implements the 'io.Reader' interface?).

Comment: `creating the csv.Reader once, then feeding it the chan content somehow`. You could use a `io.Pipe`, sink the content of the chan into the write part, give the read part to the csv reader, drain the csv reader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following to convert a channel of strings to a reader:

```
type chanReader struct {
    c   chan string
    buf string
}

func (r *chanReader) Read(p []byte) (int, error) {

    // Fill the buffer when we have no data to return to the caller
    if len(r.buf) == 0 {
        var ok bool
        r.buf, ok = <-r.c
        if !ok {
            // Return eof on channel closed
            return 0, io.EOF
        }
    }

    n := copy(p, r.buf)
    r.buf = r.buf[n:]
    return n, nil
}
```

Use it like this:

```
r := csv.NewReader(&chanReader{c: feederChan})
for {
    a, err := r.Read()
    if err != nil {
        // handle error, break out of loop
    }
    // do something with a
}
```

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ciisM8FbJ_9)

If the application assumes that newlines separate the values received from the channel, then append a newline to each value received:

```
        ...
        var ok bool
        r.buf, ok = <-r.c
        if !ok {
            // Return eof on channel closed
            return 0, io.EOF
        }
        r.buf += "\n"
        ...
```

The `+= "\n"` copies the string. If this does not meet the application's efficiency requirements, then introduce a new field to manage line separators.

```
type chanReader struct {
    c chan string  // source of lines
    buf string     // the current line
    nl bool        // true if line separator is pending
}

func (r *chanReader) Read(p []byte) (int, error) {

    // Fill the buffer when we have no data to return to the caller
    if len(r.buf) == 0 && !r.nl {
        var ok bool
        r.buf, ok = <-r.c
        if !ok {
            // Return eof on channel closed
            return 0, io.EOF
        }
        r.nl = true
    }

    // Return data if we have it
    if len(r.buf) > 0 {
        n := copy(p, r.buf)
        r.buf = r.buf[n:]
        return n, nil
    }

    // No data, return the line separator
    n := copy(p, "\n")
    r.nl = n == 0
    return n, nil
}
```

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/wqaxGIBd2fO).

Another approach is to use an io.Pipe and goroutine to convert the channel to a io.Reader as suggested in a comment to the question. A first pass at this approach is:

```
var nl = []byte("\n")

func createChanReader(c chan string) io.Reader {
    r, w := io.Pipe()
    go func() {
        defer w.Close()
        for s := range c {
            io.WriteString(w, s)
            w.Write(nl)
            }
        }
    }()
    return r
}
```

Use it like this:

```
r := csv.NewReader(createChanReader(feederChan))
for {
    a, err := r.Read()
    if err != nil {
        // handle error, break out of loop
    }
    // do something with a
}
```

This first pass at the io.Pipe solution leaks a goroutine when the application exits the loop before reading the pipe to EOF. The application might break out early because the CSV reader detected a syntax error, the application panicked because of a programmer error, or any number of other reasons.

To fix the goroutine leak, exit the writing goroutine on write error and close the pipe reader when done reading.

```
var nl = []byte("\n")

func createChanReader(c chan string) *io.PipeReader {
    r, w := io.Pipe()
    go func() {
        defer w.Close()
        for s := range c {
            if _, err := io.WriteString(w, s); err != nil {
                return
            }
            if _, err := w.Write(nl); err != nil {
                return
            }
        }
    }()
    return r
}
```

Use it like this:

```
cr := createChanReader(feederChan)
defer cr.Close() // Required for goroutine cleanup
r := csv.NewReader(cr)
for {
    a, err := r.Read()
    if err != nil {
        // handle error, break out of loop
    }
    // do something with a
}
```

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/FuVVNVwX8ts).

Answer (score 1):

Even though "ThunderCat's" answer was really useful and appreciated, I ended up using io.Pipe() "as mh-cbon mentioned" which is much simpler and looks like more efficient (explained below):

```
rp, wp := io.Pipe()
go func() {
    defer wp.Close()
    for i := range feederChan {
        fmt.Fprintln(wp, i)
    }
}()

r := csv.NewReader(rp)
for { // keep reading
    a, err := r.Read()
    if err == io.EOF {
        break
    }
    // do stuff with 'a'
    // ...
}
```

The io.Pipe() is synchronous, and should be fairly efficient: it pipes data from writer to a reader; I fed the csv.NewReader() the reader part, and created a goroutine that drains the chan writing to the writer part.

Thanks a lot.

EDIT: ThunderCat added the io.Pipe approach to his answer (after I posted this I guess) ... his answer is much more comprehensive and was accepted as such.